# How can I render two list with dynamic height items using DOM recycling libraries such as 'react-window' or 'react-vizualaized'

Tags: react-virtualized, react-window

I have a custom infinite scroll list of `Unsplash` images, each item has a dynamic height. I want to use two lists under one `outerElementType` to keep the shuffled layout, how can I achieve it using `react-window` or `react-vizualaized` libraries. I attached an example of what I want. I can't use `VariableSizedGrid` as it makes cells equal. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not know, this layout is called `Masonry layout` which is supported by 'react-visualized' [example](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/Masonry.)